# How to pass authorization token in header to react Axios.post?

Tags: reactjs, rest, api, post, axios

My application with React, Express, MongoDB.

I want to pass auth token with header for Axios post request.

But, when I am trying to pass it, getting 403 error (Forbidden).

**Local Storage**

here I am retrieving all auth data from local storage

```
export function authHeader() {
    // return authorization header with basic auth credentials
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

    if (user && user.token) {
        return { Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}` };
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}
```

**Axios.post**

here i am calling the axios post request

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios';
import { authHeader } from '../../../helpers'

export default class SubAdmin extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            user: {},
            users: [],
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            items: []
        }
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')),
            users: { loading: true }
        });
        Axios.post('http://localhost:4200/api/viewSubAdmin', 
                    {
                        headers: authHeader()
                    }).then(
          result => {
              console.log(result);

            this.setState({
              isLoaded: true,
              items: result.data
            });
          },
          error => {
            this.setState({
              isLoaded: true,
              error
            });
          }
          );
      }
```

**API Header and Response**

this is the response i am getting from my browser

```
Request URL: http://localhost:4200/api/viewSubAdmin
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: [::1]:4200
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 9
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 23 Mar 2020 10:04:33 GMT
ETag: W/"9-PatfYBLj4Um1qTm5zrukoLhNyPU"
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 171
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host: localhost:4200
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36
{headers: {,…}}
headers: {,…}
Authorization: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhZG1pbiI6IjEyMzQ1Njc4OSIsImlhdCI6MTU4NDk1MDM3MH0.Bk4q3qEsVrA8TDn7Bbk5M689B-6uVfg4r9FTmfDTWc4"
```

My postman call is working fine

```
POST: http://localhost:4200/api/viewSubAdmin
Headers: Authorization:"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhZG1pbiI6IjEyMzQ1Njc4OSIsImlhdCI6MTU4NDk1MDM3MH0.Bk4q3qEsVrA8TDn7Bbk5M689B-6uVfg4r9FTmfDTWc4",
Response Body: {
    "subadmin_details": [
        [
            {
                "isBlocked": false,
                "_id": "5e5749872eb4ab0ff5c037f9",
                "name": "abcd",
                "password": "123456",
                "admintype": "subadmin"
            },
            {
                "isBlocked": false,
                "_id": "5e574b4a2eb4ab0ff5c037fb",
                "name": "abcde",
                "password": "123456",
                "admintype": "subadmin"
            },
            {
                "isBlocked": false,
                "_id": "5e57c2b7fe57bc7a7165cd64",
                "name": "12345678",
                "password": "12345678",
                "admintype": "subadmin",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "isBlocked": false,
                "_id": "5e57c31594c9287afdf186f9",
                "name": "1234567",
                "password": "1234567",
                "admintype": "subadmin",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "isBlocked": false,
                "_id": "5e57c3266dfbde7b1507453a",
                "name": "123456",
                "password": "123456",
                "admintype": "subadmin",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: I am not sure whether this will work, but you can try once. Can you do headers: () => authHeader() in you axios post-call.

Comment: nope not working, by the way, thanks for sharing your thoughts

Comment: I saw the postman response and compared with your local request. I think the H in Headers is capital in postman, but it is small in your local.

Comment: I tried that too but no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Axios.post` receive `url`, `data` and `headers` as parameters in order. If you only pass `url` and `headers`, you have to pass `null` as `data`

```
axios.post(url, null, headers)
```

or you can try `Axios api`

```
Axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:4200/api/viewSubAdmin',
    headers: authHeader()
}).then.....
```

Comment: thanks @iamhuynq, you save my day, can you explain why my code wasn't working

Comment: not sure but i think axios post expects to have data passed as a parameter, if you only pass URL and headers, the headers are treated as data. So i think you can pass `null` to request `axios.post(url, null, headers)` and it maybe can fix this error

Comment: glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

There is a little bit of error in your code I have revised your code. Please replace your axios call with the following code and check

```
Axios.post('http://localhost:4200/api/viewSubAdmin',{
            headers: authHeader()
          }).then(result => {
              console.log(result)
              this.setState({
               isLoaded: true,
               items: result.data
              })
            }).catch(error => {
                this.setState({
                 isLoaded: true,
                 error
               })
              });
```